# How do I get rid of "Cannot resolve property key" in fmt:message tags in JSPs in Intellij

Tags: java, jsp, ide, intellij-idea, jstl

This one has been bugging me for a while now.

Is there a way I can stop Intellj IDEA from reporting missing keys in  tags?

My messages are not stored in property files so the issue does not apply in my case.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 7.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [reported this as an issue](http://jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEADEV-30407) to JetBrains and according to their issue report this is fixed in "Diana 8858". AFICT that means this will be fixed in IDEA 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can disable every hint or error marker in IDEA. Please tell us the version of IDEA that you use.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought also. However for this error the entire text of the error message is “Cannot resolve property key” and no indication of what Inspection the message comes from.